# how to download free Games

Tags: games, downloads, free

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/motorbike/
not able to down load games from here.

From where do I download free games for my ubuntu.

Comment: Why can't you download from the link you gave? What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

### 1. From apps.ubuntu.com

You should be able to download from the link you gave, just click on the Software Center icon:

[image]

If that doesn't work, you might just need to associate `apt://` links with the Software Center.

### 2. Software Center

Alternatively, you can install this and many more games using the Software Center. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and type `Sofwtare`:

[image]
Click on the first result, which will launch Ubuntu's Software Center. Then, navigate to `Games`:

[image]

Once there, you will be able to install many different games easily.

### 3. From the command line

You can also install packages (games included) with `apt-get install`. The specific game you mention does not seem to be available in the Ubuntu repositories, but many otehrs are. For example, you can install a pacman game with:

```
sudo apt-get install pacman
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this game from the Software Center. Open Ubuintu Software Center from the Unity Dash and search for motorbike. You can also find all sorts of other games there.